# Redirecting/rewrite part of domain to a different domain

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, rewrite

I have a problem I've been trying to solve using URL rewriting but I can't get it to act the way I want. I have something of an odd scenario. I apologize that this question isn't formatted very nicely, as I have to figure this out quickly.

I have two servers in separate locations. Both running IIS.

One server has a Default Web Site with many web applications under it. They are visited using

domain.com/Site1

domain.com/Site2

domain.com/Site3

The other server has

new.domain.com/Site1

new.domain.com/Site3

I need a request to `domain.com/Site1` to automatically redirect to `new.domain.com/Site1` - however, I can't have `domain.com/Site2` redirect to anything, it has to be a rule on that particular child application. On top of which, any requests, like `domain.com/Site1/Really/Long/Path....` should redirect to `new.domain.com/Site1/Really/Long/Path....`

I've tried many things, this is my latest attempt. It doesn't appear to do anything, so obviously I'm not getting something:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Datacenter Redirect" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*domain.com*" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="new.domain.com/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Could anyone please point me in the right direction? I'm moderately familiar with IIS, but not rewriting.

domain.com is IIS 7.5

Answer (score 0):

I don't have anything to test this on, but should be something close to this I believe...

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Datacenter Redirect" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="domain.com/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="new.domain.com/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

That R:1 may need to be R:2 but I'm not certain.

Then you'll need to set a condition to only do this for Site1 if you don't want this redirect occurring with Site2 if I'm reading your question correctly.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module